# CORS issue in Webpack

Tags: angular, cors, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a n Angular2/webpack project that when I make HTTP requests (i.e. getting google trends from http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/), it responds with the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I  tried every single solution that offered in SO or the webpack repository. Including modifying the webpack.config.js and adding required headers manually, or adding headers to my request inside my angular code, etc.

## webpack.config.js

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: { aggregateTimeout: 300, poll: 1000 },
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
    }
},
```

But so far no luck.

The weird thing is when I inspect the code and check the Network tab I see the status code is 200:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8Dir.png

But the console shows the error I mentioned earlier.

The other thing worth mentioning is when I request the same URL through Yahoo APIs, it works fine and I get no error in my console:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fhawttrends.appspot.com%2Fapi%2Fterms%2F%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=
```

It is the same project with two different approaches. To me it is like places like yahoo api can handle CORS requirements and webpack can't do that. Am I right?
I wonder if someone is kind enough to explain why is that happening and how to work around it.
Thank you.

p.s. I would happily use yahoo apis in my project but the thing is it reorients and messes up the json response a little which is not ideal. Besides I'm more interested in the root cause of this issue and the way(s) that we can fix it.

Edit:
Turns out that CORS and JSONP are not supported in hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/
I would be deeply apprecieted if someone show me how else I can get the json contents of that URL in my angular 2 code. tx

Comment: Hi, @Sohail Salehi! Did you find a solution to this? I'm having exactly same problem and i'd be glad if you could share some knowledge...

Answer (score 1):

Try setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to * on your backend.

Comment: Thanks Olexa but as I mentioned in my question I have tried rather a complete set of headers already. In webpack.config.js for example I have tied this:
`  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: { aggregateTimeout: 300, poll: 1000 },
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
    }
  },`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have added these settings on your frontend, but you need your backend to allow headers, origin and whatever else.

Frontend is your origin is this case, which you should allow on a backend

Comment: Thanks for your response Olexa. I have two questions here. 1) Assuming that whatever we do will be translated to a HTTP request with a bunch of headres, does it really matter where (frontend/backend) that header comes from?
2) For web apps who doesn't have a backend how do you resolve thsi issue?
Thanks again.

Comment: this may be useful. there is no need to change backend
https://www.positronx.io/handle-cors-in-angular-with-proxy-configuration/